# Writing Codesnippets to use in method chaining

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, code-snippets

### The Goal

Write codenippet which produces this result: `.Select(k => new {  })`

### The test snippet body

```
<Header>
    <Title>SelectAnonymous</Title>
    <Shortcut>selectAnonymous</Shortcut>
    <Description>Shortcut for creating Selects with an anonymous object.</Description>
</Header>
<Snippet>
    <Declarations>
        <Literal>
            <ID>ParamName</ID>
            <ToolTip>The name of the parameter</ToolTip>
            <Default>x</Default>
        </Literal>
    </Declarations>
    <Code Language="CSharp">
        <![CDATA[.Select($ParamName$ => new { $end$ })]]>
    </Code>
</Snippet>
```

### The Probem

Visual Studio doesn't suggest using code snippets when chaining methods like this: `dummyObjectList.selectAnonymous`, it only suggest methods at that point.

### The Question

Is it possible to "teach" Visual Studio or to alter the Code Snippet in such a way that Visual Studio would suggest using the snippet along side the existing methods (while chaining methods as described above)?

### The Tech

Visual Studio 2019

### The Struggle

Is Real

Comment: Plus one for "The struggle -- is real"

Comment: *bows politely*

Comment: I don't think you can do this, VS intellisense is context sensitive and only suggests snippets for a blank line.

Comment: @RonBeyer thanks for the input, I was affraid it might be like that :/

Comment: Is there a work around for that that you can think of?

Comment: As a workflow workaround, could you just use Ctrl+K, Ctrl+X to insert your snippet at the cursor?

Comment: inefficient @patrickb but not a bad work around indeed :D

Comment: might actually implement a ToDictionary code-snippet now
Thaat might infact save time how often I have to do `.Select(v => { key1, key2 } ).ToDictionary(k => key1, k => key2)`